# Controlling GIF animation with Glide

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide, animated-gif

I'm using `Glide` to load animated GIF animation into `ImageView`. It works as intended, looping indefinitely:

```
GlideApp.with(getContext())
            .load(R.raw.my_gif_animation)
            .into(this)
```

I want to add vibration every time the GIF animation cycle starts (or ends), but I couldn't find any callback, listener or frame counter, which I could use to learn when the animation cycle has started (or ended). Answers welcomed both in `Java` and `Kotlin`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem, it turns out that we have access to frames of the GIF animation after the resource was loaded. Using this information inside a running `Thread`, I was able not only to listen to the end/start of the animation but event to adjust very precisely the timing with respect to the frame of the animation.

Here is my working code in `Kotlin` (in `Java` it would be very similar):

```
GlideApp.with(getContext())
            .asGif()
            .load(R.raw. my_gif_animation)
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {

                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any,
                    target: Target<GifDrawable>,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onResourceReady(
                    resource: GifDrawable?,
                    model: Any,
                    target: Target<GifDrawable>,
                    dataSource: DataSource,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    myThread = Thread(Runnable {
                        while (true) {
                            if (resource?.isRunning == true) {
                                if (resource.frameIndex == 10).toInt()) {
                                    // This code will be executed every time the 10th frame of the GIF animation is played.. 
                                }
                                if (Thread.interrupted()) break
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    myThread?.start()
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(this)
```